# SQL Server Replication - best way to get last_distsync?

Tags: sql-server, replication, database-replication

We're trying to find out when subscriptions are hanging and falling out of date due to desktop heap issues.  The best way we've seen is by using last_distsync, gotten from running

```
 [distribution].sys.sp_replmonitorhelpsubscription @publisher = @mypublisher, @publication_type = 0
```

However, because it's got an INSERT EXEC, you can't easily save it to a table from within SQL - even doing this won't work (it may work occasionally, then you get "An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested."):

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000), @params NVARCHAR(4000), @mypublisher sysname, @myrefreshpolicy NCHAR(1), @mypublication_type int
SELECT @sql = 'exec [distribution].sys.sp_replmonitorhelpsubscription @publisher = @mypublisher, @publication_type = 0',
@params = N'@mypublisher sysname', @mypublisher = @@servername
INSERT INTO #tmp_subscriptiondata
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @params, @mypublisher = @mypublisher
```

Short of (and this is where I'm heading next) using a Powershell script and invoke-sqlcmd2 to write it, is there a way purely within SQL, to get the info out of that SP?  I'm looking at writing a knock-off, but it appears that I'm hitting limits of my access, even as sysadmin (took the SP, and made it insert into a table, and got this)

```
Msg 2760, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_replmonitorhelpsubscription2, Line 1084
The specified schema name "sys" either does not exist or you do not have permission to use it.
```

Comment: Does Hilary's or Paul's reply in this thread help?  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreplication/thread/bd76b9dd-d840-4f4a-9a15-9f0ac13d82ac

Comment: That's exactly it! Hilary's "run it twice" failed a couple times, but Paul Ibison's (replicationanswers.com) appears to be exactly what I wanted. Thanks, @Brandon!